# Handling errors in Mongoose async/await call

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I have an async function which looks up a Mongoose document by its ID and deletes it. My question is, is it ok to just have a catch clause to handle any error, or should I send in a callback as well (to catch any Mongoose errors?).

```
const myAsyncFunction = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await myModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.docId)
      req.flash('info', 'Document was deleted.')
      res.redirect('/')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Or should I have

```
   await myModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.docId, function (error, user) {
        if (error) {
        // etc
        }    
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moongoose by default has callback style functions. In your case you need to add `.exec()` to be able to `await` it and catch exceptions. So something like this

```
const myAsyncFunction = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await myModel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.docId).exec();
      req.flash('info', 'Document was deleted.')
      res.redirect('/')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
}
```